# Issue with using different emails for Firebase and for Play Store upload?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play, google-play-services

I'm using a certain Gmail address for the Firebase database in my Android app. I've put the `google-services.json` file in my app from that Gmail address' Firebase account/project, etc.

However, I uploaded my app to the Play Store with a complete new/different Gmail account/address. Is this an issue? I'm afraid that my Firebase isn't going to work because of this mismatch.

Any advice/links would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, Its not an issue. For my play store app playstore email and firebase email both are different and my app working fine